# Swift: Unexpectedly found nil

Tags: ios, swift

I'm not sure where the nil value is here. I also tried explicitly allocating the error var and still had the issue. The code is taken almost directly from Twitter documentation.

```
let statusesShowEndpoint = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/profile_banner.json?"
let params = ["screen_name":"twitter"]
var clientError :NSError?

let request = Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.URLRequestWithMethod(
            "GET", URL: statusesShowEndpoint, parameters: params,
           error: &clientError)

    if request != nil {
        Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.sendTwitterRequest(request) {
                (response, data, connectionError) -> Void in
                if (connectionError == nil) {
                    var jsonError : NSError?
                    let json : AnyObject? =
                    NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,
                        options: nil,
                        error: &jsonError)
                }
                else {
                    println("Error: \(connectionError)")
                }
        }
    }
    else {
        println("Error: \(clientError)")
    }
```

I get this error on the request:

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: The error says that you're unwrapping a value that has nil inside but you should check if that optionnal if filled before unwrapping it. You need to post more code if you want us to debug.

Comment: I've added the full method code. The code is almost directly from official Twitter documentation. My only change is the REST call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't spent much time with the twitter api, but the http endpoint you are trying to access requires that you have the qAuth authority have you done this? as the http link is coming back "bad authentication data" when i try to access it

Comment: I think you are correct. It was a problem with my setup. TwitterKit required a line in the AppDelegate which I was missing. I'll mark you correct once the necessary time limit expires.